# Affordable, non-contaminating flexible tubing for common acids

Tags: materials, equipment

Which tubing material is affordable, flexible, widely available, and suited for transporting very pure acids ("puriss." products) in their most concentrated form without contaminating them?

PTFE seems compatible with most if not all of them, but I don't think it's very flexible, and I'm not sure whether PTFE hoses would be affordable (nor where I could buy some).

Comment: Usually if you require very high purity chemicals (like semiconductor grade) there is a good enough reason to spend enough money to get the proper tubing.

Comment: @Jon_Custer: What is the proper tubing?